# Call sub-process in Python with args and read the stdout

Tags: python, subprocess

I am try to call one script from another script in Python. I'm doing this with `subprocess` OK with one call, but I don't know how make more than one call to the same sub-process.

I have a GUI, then I call my Python script called simulator.py.

**simulator.py:**

```
while 1:
    try:
        comando = raw_input('>> ')
        cmds = comando.split(' ')
        cmds = filter(None, cmds)

    except EOFError:
        break
    if not comando: continue
    elif cmds[0] == 'c':
        print "works first cmd"
    elif cmds[0] == 'm':
        print "works second cmd"
```

In the script where I implement the GUI, I want to start simulator.py in a sub-process when I press the button "load simulator". With other buttons, I want to send different messages to the same sub-process previously opened.

```
#load simulator method
term = subp.Popen('python simulator.py', shell=True, stdout=subp.PIPE, stdin=subp.PIPE, stderr=subp.PIPE)
resp, error = term.communicate("c some_argument")
print resp
self.spT

#click other button method
term = self.spT
resp, error = term.communicate("m some_argument")
print resp
```

That code causes an error. Then I tried with this:

```
#load simulator button method
term = subp.Popen('python simulator.py', shell=True, stdout=subp.PIPE, stdin=subp.PIPE, stderr=subp.PIPE)
term.stdin.write("c argument")
term.stdin.close()
print term.stdout.read()
self.spT = term
```

And when I press the other button, it calls the same sub-process and sends it the other "command" and other argument:

```
#button X to send other arg to the same subprocess
term = self.spT
term.stdin.write("m argument")
term.stdin.close()
print term.stdout.read()
```

But that causes an error too. I have also tried with `term.stdin.flush`, `wait`, etc. I have tried some examples on the Internet and here as well. I can't find one that will do the thing that I want.

Do I need to use threads? How can I implement this functionality? Can the sub-process still be running without hanging my GUI? Do I have to use another module?

Comment: why don't you use some real IPC-mechanism?

Comment: If you're only worried about your GUI freezing, then yes, you can use threads instead of a subprocess.

Comment: [`.communicate()` waits for the process to exit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) therefore you shouldn't call it more than once for the same process. *"I can't find one that will do the thing that I want."* -- in essence, it is what programmers do: they teach computers new tricks so that the computer could "do the thing that <you/customer/boss/people/etc> want". Have you tried `import simulator; simulator.some_function(*args)`? You could put the code into separate thread/process (threading, multiprocessing modules) if needed.